# Inject javascript into HtmlDocument in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, html

Is there a simple way to inject a javascript into a HtmlDocument object without using PhantomJS? 
Is there such a method in HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument class?

Any advice is apreciated,
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can** inject a script tag (with script in it) in a HTMLDocument.

You still need something to execute the javascript though. If you want your c# code to somehow evaluate the result of the javascript - especially if you are doing dom manipulation - then PhantomJS is probably the best way to go as it's a headless browser that you can run without user interaction and interface.

The short answer is yes, but i think what you want is not possible without an engine that knows both javascript and the html dom. There are alternatives to PhantomJS like http://slimerjs.org/ so my cheeky answer is still yes ;)

Hint: Don't be afraid to run PhantomJS or the like.

Comment: Yes I am doing DOM manipulation. I think I will try to use PhantomJS after all. Can you please provide an example of how I can get a javascript variable in C#?

Comment: For example I have a variable var price = productPrice();  I want to evaluate the function productPrice() and get the price in C# using PhantomJS.

Comment: Are you doing testing on a website, or are you trying to automate a task, or are you perhaps 'scraping' a site? I think context will help a lot here.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the element with

```
HtmlElement script = doc.CreateElement("SCRIPT");
```

Set the value with the script that you want and then attach to the Header of the HtmlDocument